# QSignalMapper and original Sender()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a bunch of `QComboBox`es in a table. So that I know which one was triggered I remap the signal to encode the table cell location (as described in [Selecting QComboBox in QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332110/selecting-qcombobox-in-qtablewidget))

(Why Qt doesn't just send the cell activated signal first so you can use the same current row/column mechanism as any other cell edit I don't know.)

But this removes all knowledge of the original sender widget. Calling `QComboBox* combo = (QComboBox* )sender()` in the slot fails, presumably because `sender()` is now the `QSignalMapper`.

I can use the encoded row/column to lookup the `QComboBox` in the table widget but that seems wrong. Is there a more correct way to do it?

e.g.:

```
// in table creator
_signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

 // for each cell
    QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
    connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), _signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    _signalMapper->setMapping(combo, row);

   // and finally       
   connect(_signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this, SLOT(changedType(int)));

 // slot
 void myDlg::changedType(int row)
 {      
        QComboBox* combo = (QComboBox* )sender(); // this doesn't work !!
 }
```

**EDIT**: Added for future search: there is a new book "**Advanced Qt Programming**" by Mark Summerfield that explains how to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not connect the QComboBox's signal straight to your slot?

```
QComboBox *combo = ...
connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(changedType(int)));
```

And then in your slot you can use the sender() method to retrieve the QComboBox that was changed.

```
void myDlg::changedType(int row)
{
    QComboBox *combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox *> sender();

    if(combo != 0){
        // rest of code
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to use the QSignalMapper method you would just need to change your slot to use the mapping you set up:

```
void myDlg::changedType(int row)
{
    QComboBox *combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(_signalMapper->mapping(row));

    if(combo != 0){
        // rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: The second example is how I would recommend doing this.  I imagine the mapping functions were included in the QSignalMapper class for cases just like this one.

Comment: 1 - Because then I can get a pointer to the actual combobox - but I don't know which table cell it was in, so I don't know which record to change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact answer, but maybe you should use:  QComboBox* combo = qobject_cast(sender()) instead of QComboBox* combo = (QComboBox* )sender(). Someting like this:

```
 QObject* obj = sender();
 QComboBox* combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(obj);
 if(combo)
 {
  doSomethingWithCombo(combo);
 }
 else
 {
  // obj is not QComboBox instance
 }
```

But maybe QSignalMapper really substitutes itself instead of real sender...

Comment: IIRC qobject_cast does the same thing as a regular cast, it just has a few internal checks.

Comment: At least, this cast will return 0, if there are type mismatch (specified type != requested type)