# How to Get Many QComboBoxes' Text from QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

i have inserted **lots of** QComboBox into a QTableWidget with setCellWidget (I don't know the number of qcomboboxes because it's coming from MySQL). But when I want to get its text from table with

```
self.table.item(0,1).itemText()
```

or

```
self.table.item(0,1).text()
```

or

```
self.table.item(0,1).currentText()
```

**it doesn't work**. 
Normally I can get text with `combobox.currentText()` but table has many comboboxes and I don't know the row and column (x, y) info. So I should use something like ***.item(14,1).text()***

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Are you trying to extract the selected string from a particular QComboBox? All strings? All QComboBoxes? How do you decide which elements are selected if you "don't usually know the row and column"? Without further information and/or some code excerpts your question is too ambiguous to answer properly.

Comment: Ok. Look at this picture: http://i.imgur.com/1aiMNF6.png I want to get the text "abc" without using combobox.currentText(). I have to call it with row and column info.

Comment: What happens when you call `self.table.item(row,col).currentText()`? I don't see why that shouldn't work

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'currentText'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've used `setCellWidget`, then calling `cellWidget(0,1)` instead of `item(0,1)` will return you a QWidget instead of a QTableWidgetItem.

You may need to cast this QWidget to a QComboBox, but then you should be able to call `currentText()`.

Comment: I can't remember if you need to cast. First try just calling self.table.cellWidget(0,1).currentText().

Comment: Oh my god, it is perfectly worked. How did I miss that?

Comment: @FlamFace   self.table.cellWidget(0,1).currentText()  <----- this is for python. How can I use this for qt c++

Comment: I found solution for my problem -------->>>
          QComboBox* combo=(QComboBox*) webFilterCat -> cellWidget(i, 2);
             qDebug() <<  combo -> currentText();

for qt c++

Answer (score 0):

If your want to use;

```
self.table.item(0,1).itemText()
```

or

```
self.table.item(0,1).currentText()
```

or

```
self.table.item(0,1).text()
```

I can't use item widget directly.  I suggest your use item delegate `QtGui.QItemDelegate`, for more information your can search in qt example to implement this delegate, And I have little example, hope is helps;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.listsData = ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3']

    def createEditor (self, parentQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            editorQWidget = QtGui.QComboBox(parentQWidget)
            editorQWidget.clear()
            for data in self.listsData:
                editorQWidget.addItem(data)
            return editorQWidget
        else:
            return QtGui.QItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parentQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

    def setEditorData (self, editorQWidget, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            index, _ = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toInt()
            editorQWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.setEditorData(self, editorQWidget, indexQModelIndex)

    def setModelData (self, editorQWidget, modelQAbstractItemModel, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            index = editorQWidget.currentIndex()
            modelQAbstractItemModel.setData(indexQModelIndex, index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.setModelData(self, editorQWidget, modelQAbstractItemModel, indexQModelIndex)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editorQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            editorQWidget.setGeometry(optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.updateEditorGeometry(self, editorQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            value, _ = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toInt()
            self.drawDisplay(painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect, QtCore.QString(self.listsData[value]));
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # Setup row & column data
        listsVerticalHeaderItem = ['Device 1', 'Device 2', 'Device 3', 'Device 4', 'Device 5']
        self.setRowCount(len(listsVerticalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setVerticalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsVerticalHeaderItem[index]))
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        listsHorizontalHeaderItem = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
        self.setColumnCount(len(listsHorizontalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsHorizontalHeaderItem[index]))
        self.myQCustomDelegate = QCustomDelegate()
        self.setItemDelegate(self.myQCustomDelegate)
        # Test insert data
        index = 2
        self.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(index)))
        # Test read data
        index = int(self.item(0, 0).text())
        print self.myQCustomDelegate.listsData[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget()
    myQCustomTableWidget.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

---

**`QtGui.QItemDelegate` reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html

**Spin Box Delegate Example (C++, also your can implemented in python)** : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html

---

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

```
self.nameoftablewidget.cellWidget(row,col).currentText()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.